# How to create a horizontal loading progress bar?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

When uninstalling an android application, or do some configuration, there will show such a horizontal progress bar, like following picture:

[image: progress bar]

It's not the same style like `@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal`.

How to use it in my own application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964520/android-custom-horizontal-progress-bar-animation/15788598#15788598

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It is `Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal` on my phone, if I set `android:indeterminate="true"`

Comment: Also, be sure to set height to `wrap_content` (or something bigger), I've lost almost an hour to figure out why the progress bar wasn't showing... -.-

Answer (score 216):

Just add a **STYLE** line and your progress becomes horizontal:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"      
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"      
        android:max="100" 
        android:progress="45"/>
```

Comment: It works but not dynamic horizontal bar ... need it constant on progress 45

Comment: +1 because this is the first option that worked for me. How do I set the progress color (not background)?

Comment: @TaslimOseni you can set progress bar color by progress.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));

Answer (score 83):

For using the new progress bar

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

for the old grey color progress bar use

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```

in this one you have the option of changing the height by setting minHeight

The complete XML code is:

```xml
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbProcessing"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvProcessing"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"/>
```

indeterminateOnly is set to true for getting indeterminate horizontal progress bar

Comment: What's the difference between the two styles?

Answer (score 17):

**Progress Bar in Layout**

```xml
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/download_progressbar"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/download_progress_bg_track"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/download_progress_style"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false" />
```

**download_progress_style.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale 
          android:useIntrinsicSizeAsMinimum="true" 
          android:scaleWidth="100%" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/store_download_progress" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**store_download_progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ff207d94" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 12):

Now you can create it easily using `LinearProgressIndicator` from the material design with a lot of customization for example

```xml
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Check MaterialDesign link for more information and code examples

https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#using-progress-indicators

And in Jetpack Compose you can use `LinearProgressIndicator` with color and background customization and can set progress too

```
LinearProgressIndicator()
```

Answer (score 6):

Worked for me , can try with the same

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/determinateBar"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
    android:indeterminateDuration="10"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="#208afa"
    android:progressBackgroundTintMode="multiply"
    android:minHeight="24dip"
    android:maxHeight="24dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a progress bar like this:

[image]

Then you can add this style to you progress bar:

```xml
?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal
```

Then your progress bar would look like this:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:progress="10"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:indeterminate="false" />
```

Comment: I use this for download progress indicator