# android update progress bar in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have an application that downloads files over internet. The application starts to download but dont know how to show the progress bar.
The following adapter class:

```
public class UpdateListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    // Declare Variables
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<ApplicationPojo> applicationList = null;
    private Activity activity;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private String logoName;
    private PackageManager pm;
    private ApkUpdater downloader;
    private ListView listView;

    public UpdateListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ApplicationPojo> applicationList,ListView listView)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.applicationList = applicationList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        downloader = new ApkUpdater(activity);
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return applicationList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationPojo getItem(int position) {
        return applicationList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (view == null)
        {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleapp, null);

            holder.openInstalledAppBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.openInstalledApp);
            holder.downloadBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.updateApp);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.updateProgress);
            holder.cancelBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            holder.appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.appName);
            holder.developer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.developer);
            holder.size = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.size);
            holder.appCat = (TextView) view.findViewById((R.id.appCat));
            holder.installBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.install);
            holder.removeBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            holder.catlogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.catlogo);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        try
        {
            final View finalView = view;
            holder.logo = (ImageView) finalView.findViewById(R.id.appLogo);
            logoName = applicationList.get(position).getLogo();

            Picasso.with(activity)
                    .load(IPClass.SERVERIP + logoName)
                    .into(holder.logo);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String appid = applicationList.get(position).getId();
                    int category = applicationList.get(position).getCategory();

                    Intent rec1Intent = new Intent(activity, AppView.class);
                    rec1Intent.putExtra("section","update");
                    activity.startActivity(rec1Intent);

                    AppView appView = new AppView();
                    appView.setParameters(appid, category);

                    try
                    {
                        UpdateList.updateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }
                }
            });

            final String id = applicationList.get(position).getId();
            final String path = applicationList.get(position).getPath();
            final String fileName = applicationList.get(position).getFileName();
            final String name = applicationList.get(position).getName();
            final String developer = applicationList.get(position).getDeveloper();
            final double size = applicationList.get(position).getSize();
            final String logo = applicationList.get(position).getLogo();
            final int category = applicationList.get(position).getCategory();

                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.installBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.openInstalledAppBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                holder.downloadBtn.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                holder.downloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        holder.downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                downloader.cancelDownload(name);
                                holder.cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });


                        new ApkUpdater(activity).setParameters(path, fileName, name);
                        UpdateList.updateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Adapter Exception", ex.toString());
        }
        return view;
    }




    public class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView logo;
        TextView appName;
        TextView developer;
        ImageView downloadBtn;
        ImageView installBtn;
        ImageView openInstalledAppBtn;
        ImageView cancelBtn;
        ImageView catlogo;
        ImageView removeBtn;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        TextView appCat;
        TextView size;
    }

}
```

The following is the class that downloads the file:

```
public class ApkUpdater extends Activity
{
    ///////////////////////////////////--------DECLARE VARIABLES-------------------///////////////////////////

    private Activity downloadActivity;
    private static DownloadManager manager;
    private String name;
    private String path;
    private String fileName;
    private long downloadId;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ImageView cancelBtn;
    private ImageView installBtn;
    private int bytes_downloaded;
    public static volatile int dl_progress;
    public static volatile boolean downloading;
    public static volatile boolean downloadInProgress = true;
    private Cursor cursor;


    //-------------------MAP TO STORE APP NAME WITH DOWNLOADED DATA SIZE-----//
    public static HashMap<String, Integer> applicationUpdateList = new HashMap();

    //-------------------MAP TO STORE APP NAME WITH DOWNLOAD ID--------------//
    public static HashMap<String, Long> updateIdList = new HashMap();

    //-------------------MAP TO STORE APP NAME WITH PACKAGE FILE------------//
    public static HashMap<String, String> getUpdateFileName = new HashMap<>();

    public ApkUpdater(Activity activity){ downloadActivity = activity; }

    //---------------------------FUNCTION TO GET PARAMETERS AND SET ------------------------------//

    public void setParameters(String path, String fileName, String name)
    {
        this.path = path;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.name = name;

        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/appdata/tmp/dl/");
        if(!directory.exists())
        {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        startDownload();
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////--------DOWNLOAD STARTS HERE-----------///////////////////////////

    public void startDownload() {
        try
        {
            String url = IPClass.SERVERIP + path;
            String fileToDownload = url + "/" + fileName;

            DownloadManager.Request downloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fileToDownload));
            downloadRequest.setTitle("Downloading... " + name);
            downloadRequest.setDescription(name);
            downloadRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Android/appdata/tmp/tmpdl/", fileName);
            manager = (DownloadManager) downloadActivity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            downloadId = manager.enqueue(downloadRequest);

            applicationUpdateList.put(name, 0);
            updateIdList.put(name, downloadId);
            getUpdateFileName.put(name, fileName);
            getUpdateData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Downloader: ", ex.toString());
        }
    }

        ///////////////////////////////////--------A THREAD TO CONTROL DOWNLOAD AND PROGRESS BAR -----------///////////////////////////


    public void getUpdateData()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                int appSizeInBytes;

                while (applicationUpdateList.containsKey(name))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                        q.setFilterById(downloadId);
                        cursor = manager.query(q);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                        appSizeInBytes = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                        dl_progress = (int)((bytes_downloaded * 100L)/appSizeInBytes);

                        applicationUpdateList.put(name,dl_progress);

                        int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));

                        if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL){downloadSuccessful();}

                        else if(status == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED){ downloadFailed();}
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }



    public void downloadFailed()
    {
        manager.remove(downloadId);
        File deleteFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/Android/appdata/tmp/tmpdl/" + fileName);
        deleteFile.delete();

    }

    public void downloadSuccessful()
    {
        applicationUpdateList.remove(name);
        downloadInProgress = false;


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/appdata/tmp/dl/" + fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        downloadActivity.startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Now I stuck how to update the progress bar!
Any Idea

Comment: You want a horizontal bar or an indicator???

Comment: Horizontal progress bar to show the download progress

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13409912/2715073)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show Progressbar in listview put Progressbar in your Adapter  class and call Asyntask for particular position

**DownloadTask**

```
 public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        String status = "";     
        String erroMessage = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            showprogresslayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONObject json;

            //put start download code here

                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });




            return erroMessage;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
            txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            showprogresslayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
```

**AndroidMultiPartEntity.java**

```
 public class AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity

{

    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final ProgressListener listener) {
        super();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode,
            final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode,
            final String boundary, final Charset charset,
            final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode, boundary, charset);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
    }

    public static interface ProgressListener {
        void transferred(long num);
    }

    public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

        private final ProgressListener listener;
        private long transferred;

        public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out,
                final ProgressListener listener) {
            super(out);
            this.listener = listener;
            this.transferred = 0;
        }

        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            out.write(b, off, len);
            this.transferred += len;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }

        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            out.write(b);
            this.transferred++;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }
    }
}
```

**showprogresslayout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/showprogresslayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ln_video"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ln_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <com.elizibles.fonts.MyHelveticalTextview
                    android:id="@+id/txtuploading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Uploading.."
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <com.elizibles.fonts.MyHelveticalTextview
                    android:id="@+id/txtPercentage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="0%"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```